# grails 2.4.4 : how to immediately commit each insert (aka save) in a service method.?

Tags: grails, transactions, commit

1. If I declare a method to be non transactional, then I save a record, do some stuff, save another record, will the first save be committed even if the second save fails and throws an exception, no matter what?
2. If the NonTransactional serivce method is called from another service method which IS transactional, what happens?  Does it now become part of the outer transaction, so if SomeOtherdomainObject().save() fails, the first object will be rolled back?

E.g.

```
@Transactional
class SomeService {
    @NotTransactional
    def someMethod() {
        new SomeDomainObject().save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
        // do stuff, possibly throw a RuntimeException
        new SomeOtherdomainObject().save(failOnError:true)
        // do more stuff, possibly throw a RuntimeException
    }
}
```

Called thusly (in the non transactional calling case):

```
class SomeControler{
   def someService
   def someControllerMethod() {
       someService.someMethod()
   }
}
```

Comment: Since you seem to have a setup to test, I suggest you put Hibernate logging in debug mode to see sessions and transactions work.     debug 'org.hibernate'

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware:

1. Yes.
2. Yes.

Why not set up some integration tests to confirm this (and let us know the results)?  There is [a good guide here](http://desmontandojava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/grails-pitfalls-dont-do-flushtrue-when_20.html).  Note that the test class needs to be made non-transactional in order to test the transactional functionality.  The example page I link to uses JUnit, but here is some Spock code that should do what you need.

```
// MyDomainObject.groovy
class MyDomainObject {
    String details

    static constraints = {
        // this is default anyway, but I want to make it obvious
        // not setting details and then calling save will cause an exception if
        // save's failOnError is true
        details nullable: false  
    }
}

// MyService.groovy
class MyService {
    // only make methods transactional when we explicitly want them to be
    static transactional = false

    // create 2 objects and save, 1st should save ok and second should fail
    def nonTransactionalDoubleSave() {
        def objA = new MyDomainObject()
        objA.details = "This should save ok"
        objA.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        def objB = new MyDomainObject()
        objB.details = null  // null by default, but I'm just making the point
        objB.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)  // this will trigger an exception
    }

    def nonTransactionalSingleSave() {
        def objA = new MyDomainObject()
        objA.details = "This should save ok"
        objA.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }

    @Transactional
    def transactionalSave() {
        nonTransactionalSingleSave()  // this should create 1 object
        // this should create 2 objects, but the 2nd will trigger an exception and rollback the transaction, meaning there should be no objects in the DB
        nonTransactionalDoubleSave()  
    }
}


import spock.lang.*
import grails.test.spock.*

class MyServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {    
    static transactional = false  // the test case must not be transactional

    def myService = new MyService()

    def setup() {
        // remove all my domain objects from the database that might be in there
        MyDomainObject.where{}.deleteAll()
    }

    def cleanup() {
        // remove all my domain objects from the database that a test may have created
        MyDomainObject.where{}.deleteAll()
    }

    def "Question 1: nonTransactionalDoubleSave should create 1 object only"() {
        expect: "a clean database"
        MyDomainObject.count() == 0

        when: "nonTransactionalDoubleSave is called"
        myService.nonTransactionalDoubleSave()

        then: "we get an exception but still get one object in the database"
        thrown(Exception)
        MyDomainObject.count() == 1
        def obj = MyDomainObject.list().getAt(0)
        obj.details = "This should save ok"
    }

    def "Question 2: transactionalSave should create no objects"() {
        expect: "a clean database"
        MyDomainObject.count() == 0

        when: "transactionalSave is called"
        myService.transactionalSave()

        then: "we get an exception and no objects in the database"
        thrown(Exception)
        MyDomainObject.count() == 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Note, in your code above, there is a small "gotcha".  If you put @Transactional in a method, it silently ignores the "static transactional = xxx" declaration, and the class becomes non-transactional even if you said "static transactional = true".  this has caught me out many times.  In your example it doesn't matter though, as you are saying false anyway.